# Do I need to do retraining if I want to change input dimension during testing on caffe model

Tags: machine-learning, caffe

I have recently been assigned with a project that used Caffe model. So far I manage to run the test code and get good result. But since it only output a small resolution image (128x128), I was asked to get higher resolution of it for example 512x512. Since I just started learning caffe on this project, I still have some problem understanding the flow process of caffe and I stumble upon this questions.

Here is the [deploy.prototxt](https://www.codepile.net/pile/vbk1DEoA) and here is the [train.prototxt](https://www.codepile.net/pile/J85rY6ko)

So is it actually possible to just modify the deploy.prototxt for example changing the input dimension and some number of output to the resolution that I want without retraining a new model or should I create a new model with an extra layer to enable downsampling and upsampling of higher resolution and do retraining? It would be great if someone can give me some explanation about it. Thank you for sparing your time reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network will be optimized for 128x128. So you can't put the input in 512x512 or see the output.

To use as input in 512x512 size, you must get a dataset in the 512x512 size and retrain it.
It's going to be hard and time consuming to get a dataset.

So there's also a way to change the output resolution using Python.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have checked the dataset they provided and there are actually 2 types of dataset and they both have different resolution 1 is (512x512) and the other is (178x218) and to my understanding on the train.prototxt they don't do any resizing. So how did they specify the model to train with resolution of 128x128? And can you explain the python method that you mention?

Comment: train.prototxt doesn't specify the size.
It's just that the dataset is unified to 128x128 or 512x512.

After that, you only need to specify the input size in deploy.prototxt.

The method I said is just changing the image using a library like opencv.

Comment: Can you explain how the dataset get unified to 128x128 ? I didn't understand since the dataset is 178x218 not 128x128, how did the model choose to adopt it into 128x128. And I already tried to change deploy.prototxt input into 512x512 but it return error.

Comment: Caffe uses lmdb to train.

You can't see the resolution of an image by looking at lmdb.

Even though the datasets have different image sizes, there is an option to change the image size when creating lmdb in Caffe.
So even if the dataset images were all different, the options would have changed to 128x128.